# Clang-format indents inner initialisers with continuation indent

Tags: c++, c++11, indentation, code-formatting, clang-format

I have some C++11 code with [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) rules that uses an normal indent (`IndentWidth`) of 4 and continuation indent (`ContinuationIndentWidth`) of 8. So a long function looks something like this:

```
// All indented "correctly"
void this_function_has_a_very_long_name_and_lots_of_parameters(
        int parameter_a, int parameter_b, int parameter_c)
{
    this_function_has_a_very_long_name_and_lots_of_parameters(
            parameter_a, parameter_b, parameter_c);
}
```

However, I also have data like this (note the final commas to prevent bin-packing and keep the items one per line - in real life these numbers are not just 1, 2, 3):

```
static std::vector<std::vector<int>> data{
    {
        1, // Comment
        2,
        3, // Comment
    },
};
```

The above is how I expect it to look, considering that `Cpp11BracedListStyle` is set to `false`, so it should use the block indent (4), not the continuation indent (8). From the [clang-format docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), if this is `true`:

> "Important differences: - No spaces inside the braced list. - No line
>   break before the closing brace. - Indentation with the continuation
>   indent, not with the block indent."

So, I expected to see the "block indent" (4) used. However, what I *actually* get is:

```
static std::vector<std::vector<int>> data{
    {
           1, // Comment - indented by 4 + 8!
           2,
           3, // Comment
    },
};
```

As you can see, the "inner" initialiser list is indented by 8, but the outer list's elements are only indented by 4 (as expected).

If I change `Cpp11BracedListStyle` to `true`, all levels are indented by 8 (as expected according the the documentation):

```
static std::vector<std::vector<int>> data{
        {
                1,
                2,
                3,
        },
};
```

How can I get clang-format to format these lists without changing the 8-space continuation indent that I use elsewhere in the code?

N.B. clang-format version is `7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)`, but this behaviour seems to be the same in various versions according to the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/).

A simple `.clang-format` file that applies the relevant rules as they are currently is:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
ColumnLimit: 72
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
IndentWidth: 4
```

Comment: This might be better suited to the relevant dev mailing list.